# Calculating sine and cosine

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

Are there any thing that I have to consider to improve the following code in either performance and others? Any comments and suggestions are welcome!

```
#include <iostream>

#define PI 3.1415926535897932

double sin(double x, int n = 100)
{
    double term = x;
    double sum = term;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        term *= -x * x / ((2 * i + 1) * (2 * i));
        sum += term;
    }
    return sum;
}

double cos(double x, int n = 100)
{
    double term = 1;
    double sum = term;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        term *= -x * x / ((2 * i) * (2 * i - 1));
        sum += term;
    }
    return sum;
}

double sind(double x, int n = 100)
{
    return sin(x * PI / 180, n);
}

double cosd(double x, int n = 100)
{
    return cos(x * PI / 180, n);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << cosd(180) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag this question as [tag:c], when it's not valid C code?

Comment: @200_success: Because C++ is a superset of C. I think.

Comment: It's possible to write bilingual C / C++ code, but your code isn't C-compatible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are there any thing that I have to consider to improve the following code in either performance and others?

**Argument reduction**

Both `sin()` and `cos()` benefit greatly with *argument* reduction.

Instead of many iterations, first reduce the angle to the primary range.

Following applies to `sin()`, but similar ideas applies to `cos()`.

Reduce the angle to +/-45° (π/4 radians) using common trigonometry identities.

```
sin(x + 2*π*n) = sin(x)
sin(x + π) = -sin(x)
sin(x + π/2) = cos(x)
```

Now apply your polynomial approximation.  The Taylor series converges well enough and not so many terms as 100 are needed.  (More like < 10.)

Some sample code below that quits iterating once the terms are so small as to not make a difference.  It uses the same Taylor series as OP but in a different form.  It is from a recursive implementation, yet more often a simple loop is used.

Try `x = π/4`.  (For me: 9 iterations are enough.)

```
static double my_sin_helper(double xx, double term, unsigned n) {
  if (term + 1.0 == 1.0) {
    return term;
  }
  return term - my_sin_helper(xx, xx * term / ((n + 1) * (n + 2)), n + 2);
}

// valid for [-pi/2 + pi/2]
static double my_sin_primary(double x) {
  return x * my_sin_helper(x * x, 1.0, 1);
}
```

You will get better and faster results, especially for large `x`.

**Crafted polynomials**

Advanced: Crafted polynomials (see [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials)) improve on the Taylor series and can reach the same precision with fewer terms.

This really is how many many good `sin()` functions work, but beyond the scope of this post.

**Only fair argument reduction**

π is an irrational number.  All finite `double` are rational.  It is impossible to code π *exactly* as a `double`.  Instead a nearby value is used called *machine pi*.

Thus the argument reduction of dividing by 2*machine_pi rather than 2π can inject a small error that manifests itself [sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46671801/2410359).

Advanced: Real good *radian* argument reduction requires extended precision math and is itself a very challenging problem.  [ARGUMENT REDUCTION FOR HUGE ARGUMENTS:
Good to the Last Bit](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/%7Ephatak/645/supl/Ng-ArgReduction.pdf)

**Machine pi**

Since we cannot code π , use *machine pi*.  `#define PI 3.1415926535897932` is OK for common `double`, but there is no harm in using more precise values like `3.1415926535897932384626433832795`.  This benefits should code get ported to a more precise `double`.  If using `long double`, append an `L`, `float` an `f`.

**Not so advanced: *degree* argument reduction**

In essence, do a *mod* 360.  Then the `sind(360.0)` will be 0.0 and not some annoying value like `2.449e-16`.

Really good *degree* argument reduction is far simpler.  Research `fmod()` or `remquo()`.  The reduction can be [exact](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20928253/2410359).

Example [degree argument reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31525208/2410359).